# Debian git error: undefined symbol: __gmpn_cnd_add_n

Tags: debian, symlink, git

`$ sudo apt-get install git`

`$ git clone sth`

> Cloning into 'a-folder'... git-remote-https: symbol lookup error:
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhogweed.so.2: undefined symbol:
>   __gmpn_cnd_add_n

[This post](https://techoverflow.net/blog/2015/12/06/solving-libhogweed.so.2-undefined-symbol-gmpn-cnd-add-n/) tell me to delete `/usr/local/lib/libgmp.so.10`. I do so and it works but same bug prompts every now and then (since restarting?)

I don't think deleting the file actually solve the problem. is there a more reliable solution?

```
$ ldd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhogweed.so.2

linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffda9b27000)    libnettle.so.4 =>
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnettle.so.4 (0x00007f4f7946e000)
libgmp.so.10 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10
(0x00007f4f791eb000)    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
(0x00007f4f78e40000)    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f4f798cf000)


$ ldd /usr/lib/git-core/git-remote-https

linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc50ded000)
libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007fa0a491c000)
libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007fa0a4701000)
libresolv.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007fa0a44ea000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fa0a42cd000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007fa0a40c5000)
libcurl-gnutls.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl-gnutls.so.4 (0x00007fa0a3e58000)
libexpat.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007fa0a3c2f000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fa0a3884000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fa0a4b8a000)
libidn.so.11 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libidn.so.11 (0x00007fa0a3650000)
librtmp.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librtmp.so.1 (0x00007fa0a3432000)
libssh2.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssh2.so.1 (0x00007fa0a3209000)
libnettle.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnettle.so.4 (0x00007fa0a2fd7000)
libgnutls-deb0.so.28 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls-deb0.so.28 (0x00007fa0a2cb8000)
libgssapi_krb5.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi_krb5.so.2 (0x00007fa0a2a6d000)
libkrb5.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.3 (0x00007fa0a2799000)
libk5crypto.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libk5crypto.so.3 (0x00007fa0a2568000)
libcom_err.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcom_err.so.2 (0x00007fa0a2364000)
liblber-2.4.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblber-2.4.so.2 (0x00007fa0a2155000)
libldap_r-2.4.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap_r-2.4.so.2 (0x00007fa0a1f03000)
libhogweed.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhogweed.so.2 (0x00007fa0a1cd4000)
libgmp.so.10 => /usr/local/lib/libgmp.so.10 (0x00007fa0a1a68000)
libgcrypt.so.20 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.20 (0x00007fa0a1786000)
libp11-kit.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0 (0x00007fa0a1540000)
libtasn1.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtasn1.so.6 (0x00007fa0a132c000)
libkrb5support.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5support.so.0 (0x00007fa0a1120000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fa0a0f1c000)
libkeyutils.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkeyutils.so.1 (0x00007fa0a0d18000)
libsasl2.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsasl2.so.2 (0x00007fa0a0afc000)
libgpg-error.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0 (0x00007fa0a08ea000)
libffi.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6 (0x00007fa0a06e2000)
```

Debian 8.4 on Parallels Desktop

Comment: after deleting `libgmp` from `/usr/local/lib` did you used `sudo ldconfig` for configuring dynamic linker ?

Comment: @arzyfex No. should I?

Comment: yes, please do that and try again.

Comment: @arzyfex Doesn't work. Same prompt.

Comment: If it's still not resolved, try upgrading your installed gmp version to 6.0.0. Or [read this bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=753423).

Answer (score 2):

You need to delete your local `libgmp` completely:

```
rm /usr/local/lib/libgmp.so*
```

There's no need to run `ldconfig` afterwards. `ldconfig` makes sure the appropriate symlinks are present; `libgmp.so.10` is a symlink to the latest library with that soname (run `ls -l /usr/local/lib/libgmp.so*` before deleting the files to see what I mean). Previously you deleted that symlink, but running `ldconfig` will have restored it...